# Array Output Looping

Tags: java, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm finishing up a program that shows an array given from a file, then gives you the total, average, then specific totals of certain rows. The problem I'm having is that the Array has suddenly begun looping once terminated.

I'm working this in Eclipse IDE

```
    String fileName = "";
    if (args.length == 0) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the file name :");
        fileName = sc.nextLine();
    } else {

        fileName = args[0];
    }
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\AlaynaC\\Desktop\\2darray.txt");

    try {
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(file);
        int size = fin.nextInt();
        int[][] arr = new int[size][size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = fin.nextInt();

                Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

                // The first line of the file contains the number of rows in the array.
                int noOfRows = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

                // initialize all with -1
                int array[][] = new int[noOfRows][10];
                for (int o = 0; o < noOfRows; o++) {
                    for (int g = 0; g < array[o].length; g++) {
                        array[o][g] = -1;
                    }
                }
                int index = 0;
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = sc.nextLine();
                    // Each record in the file corresponds to a row in the array.
                    String numbers[] = line.split(" ");
                    // Now feeding the data into the array.
                    for (int o = 0; o < numbers.length; o++) {
                        array[index][o] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[o]);
                    }
                    index++;
                }
                sc.close();
                // This allows the data to be printed to the console.
                System.out.println("~~Array~~");
                for (int o = 0; o < noOfRows; o++) {
                    for (int g = 0; g < array[o].length; g++) {
                        if (array[o][g] != -1)
                            System.out.print(array[o][g] + " ");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Total: " + getTotal(arr));
        System.out.println("Average: " + getAverage(arr));
        System.out.println("Row Total: " + getRowTotal(arr, 3));
        System.out.println("Column Total: " + getColumnTotal(arr, 2));
        System.out.println("Highest in Row:" + highestInRow(arr, 2));
        System.out.println("Lowest in Row:" + lowestInRow(arr, 2));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath() + " is not found!");
    }
}
```

I need the array to only display once. As of right now it is displaying multiple times once the file is entered.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the array has suddenly begun looping once terminated'? I'm not clear by what you mean by an array looping? Could you describe exactly what you are seeing in the output?

Comment: @sprinter Once the file is entered it shows the array multiple times, I need it to only show once.

Comment: How many arrays are you supposed to read out of the file? Just one?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Just one

Comment: So you've got two big outer loops that look like they're getting ready to read `size` rows of `size` columns each into `arr`.  But then, **inside of all that**, you've got all the logic to read the rows and columns of an array into **yet another array**, `array` and then print out the contents of `array`. The inner logic alone is all you need; those two outer loops seem completely unnecessary.

Comment: @KevinAnderson The problem is that I was using one loop to display the files text and another to read the numbers as int's. I need to merge those into one loop.